Overstaying in the USA want to travel to South Korea Will they let me in?
I am an Australian citizen I came in US 2023 Mar and overstayed till now (2024 Oct)
I have done not anything illegal and have no criminal records. I have not been caught and now I want to vist South Korea. (I understand I won't be able to come back to the USA for 10years)
However I have seen some things that say South Korea Immigration may not let me enter Korea if I have overstayed in the US.
How likely is it that they will not let me into Korea?

“I have done not anything illegal”. You may not have been caught (yet), but you most certainly did something illegal. Also, how did you support yourself for all this time? Did you not work while in the US?

@T-Maree You asked "Would it then be more likely to be accepted into Korea if I went by vehicle to Canada first?" Not into Canada, but Mexico! Canada passes on data to the US, Mexico doesn't, and if you enter Mexico in a car rather than on foot, your passport isn't usually checked at all.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The probability they will notice the overstay is probably low. The only obvious evidence being an entry stamp into the US quite a long time ago (if you even got one) while travelling directly from the US, but since the US is phasing out entry stamps in favour of digital kiosks, that’s quite inconclusive: they can’t say “you overstayed in the US” just by looking at your passport.
However, they may ask questions, and they could find out if they want to.
And then you may end up in some tricky waters: the usual procedure for someone who is refused entry is to be sent back from where they came from, but this is unlikely to work. So they will want to ship you to Australia, but this is a lot more complex than sending you back, especially if the airline which carried you from the US to Korea does not fly from Korea to Australia.
Which means that unless you pay for your own ticket to Australia on the spot, you may get stuck in detention until they manage to send you there. Probably not a pleasant experience.
Your best bet is probably to leave the US and return to Australia directly, and forget about travel to other countries for a very long while.

The US does not have a exit stamps, so it's literally impossible to detect an overstay from your passport stamps. And the US also doesn't have effective exit control (notably, no checks when crossing by land into Mexico), so even the US doesn't know they overstayed. How could another country find out?

@lambshaanxy The exit controls by air, sea and by land to Canada are quite efficient; the only underbelly being the Mexican border or if leaving by leisure vessel

@lambshaanxy back when all visitors got a entry stamp, if you saw someone coming directly from the US with the last entry stamp over a year ago one could at least wonder and ask a few questions (provided they even checked stamps from other countries, which is probably unlikely, though it may depend on the visited country and/or any other suspicions the agent may have). Nowadays it’s completely impossible in the case of the US.

@jcaron Yeah, since AFAIK the only people who still get stamped are immigrant visa holders and perhaps a few other cohorts

@lambshaanxy To complement on the "find out" (though that would happen only once one reaches secondary because of other suspicions), the easiest bit is often to look at the visitor's social media. Asking questions about the visitor's work/income could also be quite revealing, even if indirectly. Remember they don't necessarily have to prove anything: the onus is usually on the visitor to prove they are a bona fide visitor, and it's easy for an experienced agent to make someone trip when their story doesn't hold up.

First off, do NOT fly directly from the US, because then the Americans WILL know about your overstay, and you then cannot enter visa-free ever again, but will have to get visas for the rest of your life after the 10-year ban is lifted.
Instead, cross by land into Mexico (preferably in a car=no passport check) and fly on Aeromexico Mexico City-Seoul for instance. That way there's no record of your exit from the US and thus no black mark on your record. However, if ever returning to the US, proving you didn't overstay might prove tricky IF asked (as after all you did!)
